# Oracle OR, AND, NOT condition

Tags: oracle

> Query 1 : there're 'APP' & 'WEB' in case-when clause.

```
SELECT a_date, 
       CASE WHEN A.TOPPAGEID='MLAND' 
                OR (A.PAGEID='B047201' 
                OR B.GROUP3PAGEID='B047201') 
           THEN 'APP'
           ELSE 'WEB' 
        END AS LB, 
        COUNT(DISTINCT A.SESSIONNAME) AS SN
FROM A, B
WHERE A.a_date='20170101'
AND A.PAGEID=B.PAGEID
AND A.PAGEID IN ('LAND','MLAND')
GROUP BY A.a_date,
CASE WHEN A.TOPPAGEID='MLAND' OR (A.PAGEID='B047201' OR B.GROUP3PAGEID='B047201') THEN 'APP' ELSE 'WEB' END ;
```

> Try 1. Extract 'WEB' from Query 1

```
SELECT AA.a_date, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT AA.SESSIONNAME) AS SN
FROM (SELECT * FROM A WHERE a_date ='20170101' AND TOPPAGEID='LAND') AS AB
     LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM B) AS BB ON (AA.PAGEID=BA.PAGEID)
WHERE NOT (AA.PAGEID='B047201' OR BB.GROUP3PAGEID='B047201')
GROUP BY AA.a_date;
```

> Try 2. Extract 'WEB' from Query 1

```
SELECT AA.a_date, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT AA.SESSIONNAME) AS SN
FROM A, B
WHERE A.a_date='20170101'
  AND A.PAGEID=B.PAGEID
  AND (A.TOPPAGEID='LAND' AND (A.PAGEID!='B047201' OR B.GROUP3PAGEID!='B047201')) 
GROUP BY A.a_date;
```

I try to extract the 'WEB' from Query 1, but the results of two queries, try1 and try2 don't match with the result of 'WEB' in case-when clause. Could you direct me how to extract 'WEB' from case-when clause?

Comment: can you explain the real problem, couldn't get your point.

Comment: I can't get the point. These are different queries, whatever they do, so, what do you need to do? Do you want to rewrite the same query in different ways? And why? Please try to bettere explain what you need to do

Comment: I changed my explanation. I'd like to extract 'WEB' in case-when clause.  @MuhammadNadeem

Comment: I changed my explanation. I'd like to extract 'WEB' in case-when clause. @Aleksej

Comment: It would really help us to understand your problem if you posted code which actually works. So, valid syntax, consistent aliases, etc. You want us to spend our time helping you, the least you can do is invest some of your time framing a proper question.

Comment: I alredy put consistent valid syntax and aliases, and I didn't ask you to help me. I just want to know what the opposite condition of "A.TOPPAGEID='MLAND' OR (A.PAGEID='B047201' OR B.GROUP3PAGEID='B047201')". I tried so many cases, but the result of SN doesn't match with the result of Query1. My coworkers already tried to solve this case, but it still doesn't work. @APC – user2427306 16 mins ago

Answer (score 0):

> I just want to know what the opposite condition of
>
> ```
> A.TOPPAGEID='MLAND' OR (A.PAGEID='B047201' OR B.GROUP3PAGEID='B047201')
> ```

The inverse of `A OR B` is `NOT A AND NOT B` so:

```
( NOT A.TOPPAGEID='MLAND' ) AND ( NOT (A.PAGEID='B047201' OR B.GROUP3PAGEID='B047201') )
```

or:

```
A.TOPPAGEID!='MLAND' AND A.PAGEID !='B047201' AND B.GROUP3PAGEID != 'B047201'
```

Comment: This assumes all column values are not NULL. There was no statement of such in the post.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a_date, 
       CASE WHEN A.TOPPAGEID='MLAND' 
              OR (A.PAGEID='B047201' 
                  OR B.GROUP3PAGEID='B047201') 
            THEN 'APP'
            ELSE 'WEB' 
       END AS LB, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT A.SESSIONNAME) AS SN
FROM A
JOIN B ON A.PAGEID=B.PAGEID
WHERE A.a_date='20170101'
  AND A.PAGEID IN ('LAND','MLAND')
  AND CASE WHEN A.TOPPAGEID='MLAND' 
            OR (A.PAGEID='B047201' 
            OR B.GROUP3PAGEID='B047201') 
       THEN 'APP'
       ELSE 'WEB' END = 'WEB
GROUP BY A.a_date,
        CASE WHEN A.TOPPAGEID='MLAND' OR (A.PAGEID='B047201' OR B.GROUP3PAGEID='B047201') THEN 'APP' ELSE 'WEB' END
```

Or:

```
SELECT a_date, 
       CASE WHEN A.TOPPAGEID='MLAND' 
              OR (A.PAGEID='B047201' 
                  OR B.GROUP3PAGEID='B047201') 
            THEN 'APP'
            ELSE 'WEB' 
       END AS LB, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT A.SESSIONNAME) AS SN
FROM A
JOIN B ON A.PAGEID=B.PAGEID
WHERE A.a_date='20170101'
  AND A.PAGEID IN ('LAND','MLAND')
  AND (NOT(A.TOPPAGEID='MLAND' 
            OR (A.PAGEID='B047201' 
            OR B.GROUP3PAGEID='B047201'))
       OR A.TOPPAGEID IS NULL
       OR A.PAGEID IS NULL
       OR B.GROUP3PAGEID IS NULL)
GROUP BY A.a_date,
        CASE WHEN A.TOPPAGEID='MLAND' OR (A.PAGEID='B047201' OR B.GROUP3PAGEID='B047201') THEN 'APP' ELSE 'WEB' END
```